# Python: how to make a method uniquely callable via getitem

Tags: python, oop, methods

i want to do something like this:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self # with some additional methods, let's say for the example
                    # one extra method 'my_method' that returns 1

f = Foo()
f.a
# 0
f.my_method()
# error: my_method not defined

f[].my_method()
# 1
f[].a
#0
```

My object have some basic methods and some others that depends on the argument passed when `__getitem__` is called.

I tried something like this

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0

    class Handler:
        def __init__(self, item):
            self.item = item

        def my_method(self):
            return 1

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.Handler(item)

f = Foo()
f[].my_method()
# 1
# but i dont have access to the outer class
f[].a
# error
```

Comment: Can you explain more of your motivation for why __getitem__ ? Maybe there is another approach that can be proposed to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: I have a shape as a list of coordinates, i need to get that shape in others frames (different basis and origins), in order to list all points of the shape i need to specify the frame, and compute their coordinates by a change of basis. I will then have to run though each of these points : i want to do this : `for point in shape[frame] : ...`. In my example, Handler would have had `__iter__`, `__next__` and `__contains__ `methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this do the job the way i wanted

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._a = value

    class Handler:
        def __init__(self, item, a):
            self.item = item
            self.a = a

        def my_method(self):
            return 1

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.Handler(item, self.a)
```

I can return a custom foo object when calling getitem. I use properties to let the 'a' value in Handler be modified by the setter.

Answer (score 0):

if all you want is access to the parent object instance consider simply adding an accessor to the subclass that is created on _*getitem*_:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0

    class Handler:
        def __init__(self, item):
            self.item = item

        def my_method(self):
            return 1

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        obj = self.Handler(item)
        obj.parent = self
        return obj

f = Foo()
f[...].my_method()
# 1
f[...].parent.a
# 0
```